# Why is the error displayed when starting the application on expreess js: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhostss

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

When I try to run the hosted API app, I get the following message:

```
2022-04-11T12:32:31: Server running at http://localhost:9000

2022-04-11T12:32:31: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhostss

2022-04-11T12:32:31: at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {

2022-04-11T12:32:31: errno: -3008,

2022-04-11T12:32:31: code: 'ENOTFOUND',

2022-04-11T12:32:31: syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

2022-04-11T12:32:31: hostname: 'localhostss',

2022-04-11T12:32:31: fatal: true

2022-04-11T12:32:31: }
```

Please help me fix

index.js:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4k4q.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hostname is wrong**
according to error hostname is localhostss rather than localhost